# Emmet abbreviation for Pug "input" is inserting an unneeded #

Tags: visual-studio-code, pug, emmet

I'm working on a Pug template in VS Code and whenever I try to use the emmet abbreviation `input:text` (or any input for that matter), it resolves to `input#(type="text", name="")`.

It's not the end of the world, but it's driving me crazy, and I can't figure out why it's doing so or how to change it.

I guess my question is: is there any way to change this behavior or any place that I can draw attention to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understand why this is happening, and that my confusion was basically a misunderstanding of proper form creation.

All text inputs should have an id associated with them, so Emmet is expecting an ID in the shorthand. So this:

```
input:text#user
```

resolves to

```
input#user(type="text", name="")
```

Which works great! Too bad it took me months of confusion to I realized how daft I am!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the treatment of the attributes `id` and `class` for indent-based syntaxes (Slim, Pug, etc.).

For some reason it removes the attribute from its current position and pushes to the front the strings `#` for `id` and `.` for `class`.

This is controlled with 2 regex statements near line 3297 in
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft.VS.Code\resources\app\extensions\emmet\node_modules\vscode-emmet-helper\out\expand\expand-full.js`

Change

```
const reId = /^id$/i;
const reClass = /^class$/i;
```

to

```
const reId = /^Xid$/i;
const reClass = /^Xclass$/i;
```

You must also remove the cached version of this file in the directory
`C:\Users\__username__\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedData\__some_hex_value__`

Restart VSC and it should work.

For linux systems you have to find the location of these files.